# https implementation in iOS

Tags: ios, https

I am trying to secure client server connection using https .I know NSURLConnection delegates can handle authentication challenges but i want to know if this can be achieved for calling url without a NSURLConnection like dataWithContentsOfUrl & initWithContentsOfURL.

eg:

```
NSData *downloadData =[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:webUrl];
```

Is there a way to handle authentication to these requests also.

Comment: `dataWithContentsOfURL` is [not meant](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfURL:) for over-the-network requests anyway, since it will block the thread and hang your app. But the entire [URL Loading System](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) in iOS handles https as well as http, so you don't need to do anything special for https.

Comment: Even when there is a certificate which needed to be authenticated ??

Comment: If you're talking about server certificate validation using root certificates (which is part of https), then yes. Why not just try it? Just NSURLConnection yourself any https page on the Internet, and watch the magic happen.

Comment: I tried and it failed to load content into NSData for a https url which requires authentication. This is the error  NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9807)

Comment: Does the server present a self-signed certificate? Are you providing http credentials for the resource, and if so, how? Please provide more context.

Comment: Server is presenting a self -signed certificate. what credentials you are talking about ? can you be a little clear.

Comment: The self-signed certificate is the reason you're getting the kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL. You need to explicitly tell your code to accept the untrustworthy certificate - the default is to only accept valid certificates. There are several guides on how to do this, if indeed it's what you're asking (at this point, I have no idea). Also, your use of the word "authentication" but refusal to acknowledge "credentials" is mind-boggling. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to handle secure client server connection using `dataWithContentsOfURL:`

You have to use NSURLConnection to handle secure client server connection by using its delegate methods.